# JQueryMobile: How to start the page x pixels scrolled down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I've got a JQueryMobile site, and I want to place a div at the top, that isn't visible on the first page load, but only when the user scrolls up. It's meant to emulate a pull-to-refresh. Basically like what [these guys did](http://unionstationdenver.com/history/), using [this Javascript](http://unionstationdenver.com/lib/js/550.js). This isn't a pull-to-refresh, but they're doing what I want to, which is 'hiding' a div above the initial view.

Unfortunately, JQueryMobile waits until the site is fully loaded, then automatically scrolls all the way back up to the top. So even though I can scroll the page down immediately, a few seconds later (random time), it'll scroll back up.

Is there any way to either stop the scrolling-back-up of JQueryMobile, or to create this div using HTML/CSS?

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5820

Comment: The main culprit here seems to be line 11173 in JQueryMobile:

`11171 // window load event`
`11172 // hide iOS browser chrome on load`  
`11173 $window.load( $.mobile.silentScroll );`

Commenting out this line removes the scroll-to-top so I can simply use a $.mobile.silentScroll(35);

I'm obviously very hesitant to edit the actual JQueryMobile script, I'm not sure as to the ramifications or the design decisions behind this.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `display:none` on your header so it isn't visible, then show it and scroll at the same time. See http://jsfiddle.net/Lanny/CDhmr/1/. Even if there's a significant delay between your page being rendered and your javascript executing scroll will happen at the same time that you extend the document.

Comment: This wouldn't work if it displayed before the page finished loading, as it'd then scroll to the top and be visible. However, being a refresh button, it doesn't need to be visible immediately, so I could trigger this after 5-10 seconds. Possible solution, thanks!

Comment: +1 Probably best solution. jQuery Mobile can properly use silentScroll only in pageshow event and at that point user will see page moving.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that $.mobile.defaultHomeScroll might help here.

Haven't used JQueryMobile, but noticed this pull request on GitHub:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/pull/5751